# How to do slicing in pandas Series through elements instead of indices in case they are similar

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas Series like:

```
s = pd.Series([1,9,3,4,5], index = [1,2,5,3,9])
```

How can I obtain, say, element `'3'`? Given that I do not know exact elements in advance. I need to write a function that gets, say, first element of the Series.

series[2] understands it like 'index=2' instead of 'second element', when we do have indices.

When I do not indicate indices, the slicing works fine, just through elements.

But how can I prioritize slicing through elements if they overlap with indices?

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using boolean indexing:

```
s[s==3]
```

Given:

```
s = pd.Series([1,9,3,4,5], index = [1,2,5,3,9])
```

Let's find elements 3 and 9, use:

```
s[s.isin([9,3])]
```

Output:

```
2    9
5    3
dtype: int64
```

## Update per comment below

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html#pandas-series-iloc) for integer location:

```
s.iloc[2]
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know elements in advance, I need to write a function for getting a given element (or slice), for example, first and third, in any Series

Comment: @Alina  I think you need `iloc` for integer location unlike `loc` which uses label location.

Comment: @Alina You're welcome. Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.